# What does $A^p$ mean in EGA I's definition of "finite type"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In Chapter I of EGA, a "module of finite type" and a "finite presentation" are defined as follows (translating from the French):

> To say that an $A$-module $M$ is of finite type means that there exists an exact sequence $A^p \to M \to 0$. We say that an $A$-module $M$ admits a *finite presentation* if it is isomorphic to the cokernel of a homomorphism $A^p \to A^q$, in other words if there exists an exact sequence $A^p \to A^q \to M \to 0$.

What are $A^p$ and $A^q$ here? [Here is a PDF of EGA I.](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/EGA/EGAI.pdf) The relevant definitions are at the top of page 12.

Comment: The direct product of $p$ copies of $A$, or if you prefer, the free $A$-module of rank $p$.

Comment: Oh silly me, that's quite obvious in retrospect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $A^p$ stands for
$$\overbrace{A \oplus \cdots \oplus A}^{p \ \text{times}}$$
which is the direct sum of $p$ copies of $A$.